# Returning and passing around raw POD pointers (arrays) with Python, C++, and pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a C++ function which returns a raw `float` pointer, and another C++ function which accepts a raw `float` pointer as an argument. Something like:

```
float* ptr = something;
float* get_ptr(void) { return ptr; }
void use_ptr(float* ptr) { do_work(ptr); }
```

I want to be able to pass around pointers using Python. Something like this:

```
import my_native_functions as native
ptr = native.get_ptr()
native.use_ptr(ptr)
```

I am using pybind11 to create my native python module but I don't know how to create the bindings for the `get_ptr()` function. If I just do the following:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_native_functions, m)
{
    m.def("get_ptr", &get_ptr);
    m.def("use_ptr", &use_ptr);
}
```

the `get_ptr()` function returns a Python `Float` object. I guess this makes sense because there are no pointer types in python. However, because this is now a simple `Float`, when I call the `use_ptr()` function and iterate over the pointer in C/C++, only the first element of the array is correct. The rest are garbage. To fix this, in C++, I have to cast my pointer to/from `std::size_t`. By doing this, everything works just fine.

However, I would like to ask: Is there a "right way" of achieving the above without the casting to/from `std::size_t` with pybind11?

In case you are curious why I do that:
I do understand that what I am doing is not type-safe. Also, I never touch the pointer/integer on the Python side. I just retrieve it from one native module and pass it to another. Also, I cannot cast the pointer to some kind of numpy view because the pointer is not always on the CPU. Sometimes I want to pass around CUDA pointers. Creating a `py::array_t` from a CUDA pointer is not possible unless I copy the data (and I do not want to do that).

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the raw pointer in a custom "smart" pointer class (only pretending to be smart really) as described [here](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/smart_ptrs.html#custom-smart-pointers). You can add some additional information to this class while you're at it, such as the size of the array element and the number of elements. This would make it a generalised array descriptor on the C++ side (but not on the Python side because you are not exposing the raw pointer to Python).

For a simpler option, just wrap your pointer in any old class in order to hide it from Python. No need to expose it to Python as a custom smart pointer. Here's an example that does just that:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace py = pybind11;

template <class T> class ptr_wrapper
{
    public:
        ptr_wrapper() : ptr(nullptr) {}
        ptr_wrapper(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
        ptr_wrapper(const ptr_wrapper& other) : ptr(other.ptr) {}
        T& operator* () const { return *ptr; }
        T* operator->() const { return  ptr; }
        T* get() const { return ptr; }
        void destroy() { delete ptr; }
        T& operator[](std::size_t idx) const { return ptr[idx]; }
    private:
        T* ptr;
};

float array[3] = { 3.14, 2.18, -1 };

ptr_wrapper<float> get_ptr(void) { return array; }
void use_ptr(ptr_wrapper<float> ptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        std::cout << ptr[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(Ptr,m)
{
    py::class_<ptr_wrapper<float>>(m,"pfloat");
    m.def("get_ptr", &get_ptr);
    m.def("use_ptr", &use_ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply my friend. That is a good idea. Unfortunately, I am a bit confused with the documentation and I am not quite sure how to do what you described. Any examples are more than welcome!

Comment: @AstrOne I added an example

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit I just went down a rabbit hole on your profile, it was an interesting ride. Also, thank you kindly for this solution :)