# pybind11 how to cast pointer to/from std::size_t?

Tags: python, c++, pointers, pybind11

I see a problem from one Stackoverflow question. It is described below:

I have a C++ function which returns a raw float pointer, and another C++ function which accepts a raw float pointer as an argument. Something like:

```
float* ptr = something;
float* get_ptr(void) { return ptr; }
void use_ptr(float* ptr) { do_work(ptr); }
```

I want to be able to pass around pointers using Python. Something like this:

```
import my_native_functions as native
ptr = native.get_ptr()
native.use_ptr(ptr)
```

I am using pybind11 to create my native python module but I don't know how to create the bindings for the `get_ptr()` function. If I just do the following:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_native_functions, m)
{
    m.def("get_ptr", &get_ptr);
    m.def("use_ptr", &use_ptr);
}
```

the `get_ptr()` function returns a Python `Float` object. I guess this makes sense because there are no pointer types in python. However, because this is now a simple `Float`, when I call the `use_ptr()` function and iterate over the pointer in C/C++, only the first element of the array is correct. The rest are garbage. To fix this, in C++, I have to **cast my pointer to/from `std::size_t`**. By doing this, everything works just fine.

However, I would like to ask: Is there a "right way" of achieving the above without the casting to/from `std::size_t` with pybind11?

The above is the whole problem description that comes from AstrOne's question:[Returning and passing around raw POD pointers (arrays) with Python, C++, and pybind11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982143/returning-and-passing-around-raw-pod-pointers-arrays-with-python-c-and-pyb).

My question is  **"To fix this, in C++, I have to cast my pointer to/from std::size_t"**, how should this cast be done? Can here give me a example or more detailed explanation? I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `float*` type with `std::uintptr_t`. See below

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

float* ptr = something;
std::uintptr_t get_ptr() { return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(ptr); }
void use_ptr(std::uintptr_t ptr) { do_work(reinterpret_cast<float*>(ptr)); }
```

No pointer types will be exposed to `pybind11` now. What is doing here is just cast a pointer type to a integral type, which has no difference in binary representation.

Aside: `std::size_t` would be Ok in most platforms. As per [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t):

> On many platforms (an exception is systems with segmented addressing) std::size_t can safely store the value of any non-member pointer, in which case it is synonymous with std::uintptr_t.